# Text size issue in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView and I need to calculate it's content size before the new character appears on editing. I've tried the following:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    CGSize size = [[textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range 
                                                          withString:text]
                       sizeWithFont:textView.font
                  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textView.contentSize.width, 200)
                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return YES;
}
```

I set a breakpoint at the line with `return`. The content insets are 0 each.

The problem is that the `size` has a height of 60, but the `textView.contentSize.height` is 76 (and I enter a character, not delete one so it should be 76 if no new line is required or greater than 76 if I`m at the end of line). Anyone knows why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you run into problems with nested calls try to seperate all calls you can and put the result of them in variables. This way you can see what's hapening and what you get from each call.

Comment: I've printed every sub-result and they seemed ok.